# How are bioremediation microbes removed from the environment once they perform their function?

Tags: microbiology

In the case of bioaugmentation, microbes are introduced into the environment to clean up and absorb a certain pollutant. My question is how is that microbe then removed from the environment once it performs its function?

Comment: A bit broad.  Sometimes it will die off when food supply is too small to support the population; sometimes it will need to be removed with poisons or predators; sometimes it doesn't need to be removed as it is relatively benign to the environment.  What case of bioaugmentation are you referring to specifically?

Comment: Heavy metal bioaugmentation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to introduce conditions which hinder multiplication of the microbe such as altering the pH and emperature. This is hard to achieve in a large environment, alternatively, you can introduce a recombinant of that microbe which posses a survivability threat to the initial microbe.

Comment: Could you add some sources describing these steps actually being performed?